# Is .NET MailMessage class injection-safe?

Tags: .net, email

I wonder if [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class is protected from [e-mail injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_injection). For example, should I check values before passing them to its constructor:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromTextBox.Text, toTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MailAddress` class checks its addresses against the full BNF grammar from RFC822.  (See `MailBnfHelper`).

There is no risk of injection when using `MailMessage`s.  (Except HTML injection in your own content)

Comment: `MailAddress` does suffer from a form of injection - you can inject a second address in the DisplayName of one address. e.g. `new MailAddress("a2@b.de", "No1\" <a1@b.de>, \"No2")` turns into `"No1" <a1@b.de>, "No2" <a2@b.de>` and it even passes through `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` like that into the .eml file.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the source code and it seems there is no checks at all (except those that the params are not null)
But if you simply create a MailMessage, there should be no problem at all, because its plain text...
Only when using Alternate Views you should be aware of injections.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be only a simple check in the MailAddress class which checks if the address contains an @.