# Is there any danger of injection in sending mail with MailMessage? And if so - how should I avoid it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

This is my code:

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("...");
s.Send(m);
```

Only `subject` and `body` are user input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is .NET MailMessage class injection-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301339/is-net-mailmessage-class-injection-safe)

Comment: No, he is specifically asking about the subject and body, while that question is specifically referring to From and To (which use the MailAddress class).

Comment: @DavidHall It only mentions checking the addresses.

Comment: Are you setting IsBodyHtml to true?

Comment: @BrianMains Nope. But I wonder if it would make a difference anyway.

Comment: @ispiro Probably since with HTML, you can inject javascript, but text only wouldn't matter as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code's fine, but it depends on where "subject" and "body" are coming from. If (as you note) they are user-supplied, you want to make sure you are encoding it (HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for lack of a better one, since it gave me the de facto solution. But I'm still interested in an answer to whether the HtmlEncode is actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate **subject** and **body** then.

Comment: The entire point of this question is asking whether or not they need to be validated (e.g., does the class do it itself).

Comment: @YYY That's half the question. I _would_, actually, want to know _how_ to do it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am attempting to write up a test project to investigate this real fast, but from my look at Reflector and my reading of the documentation, the Subject and Body are strictly treated as System.Strings - this is to the point where you are welcome to explicitly set the encoding on the strings if you want (MailMessage.BodyEncoding).

Unless there is a major bug in how this class is put together, there should be no greater chance of code injection than there would be with any other string; especially if you explicitly set the BodyEncoding to be some manner of plain text, like UTF-8.

EDIT: Alternately, if you really really want to make sure that HTML isn't a part of the body you could use the regex

```
@"<[^>]*>"
```

to naively strip out anything inside a bunch of angle brackets, either with Regex.Replace(regex, string.empty) or Regex.Match and throwing on a return that indicated a match was found.

Comment: Thanks. That's what seems logical, but I don't know how to check that.

Comment: It is pretty simple.  Do you want HTML code to be 'okay' in this setup?  If so, set IsBodyHtml to True and the text encoding to something that a normal HTML parser could understand.  If not, set IsBodyHtml to false and use a text encoding that supports everything you will expect to get from whatever you're pulling your data from.  If it's just English letters, UTF-8 should be fine.  If you expect to get some other languages, Unicode may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

From the link @DavidHall posted of [Is .NET MailMessage class injection-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301339/is-net-mailmessage-class-injection-safe), @Slaks mentions that to/from is validated, but your body content is not.  So you would need to validate the subject and body.

Make sure you encode the subject and body before sending it to the user; that should be enough to handle in most scenarios.